# Is it possible to get a TCP Window Zero from an AWS ALB to a EKS pod?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, network-programming, amazon-eks

I've been having network issues with an ALB ingress in EKS, with kubectl plugin managed to Wireshark into the pod and got TCP window full, followed by TCP window Zero packet, the thing is this is from the alb to the pod and not the client to the alb.

is it possible that the alb sends a TCP window full to the pod and not the client? ive been reading around and couldn't find information that says its possible or not, also if I wanted to double-check a tcpdump should be run from the client network side, is there a way to corroborate is their network issue and not ours from our side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of debugging, the problem was with the node network, after deleting the node and creating a new node group with eksctl the problem stopped happening

Used this for sniffing pods tcpdumps:

https://github.com/eldadru/ksniff

Comment: Could you provide more details on the node network problem? also what node group settings/configuration did you create the new one with? Thanks!

Comment: Try to create a new node and instantiate the pod there, see if the error happens in the new node, the issue happened 9 months ago and cant remember more details, added the answer because of the upvotes, monitored everything with tcpdump and the problem was a TCPWINDOW 0 packet from the node